# How to add a force drag event in D3 and make the node stay where i leave it?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have a D3 api which is showing some relationship between the nodes .I want to apply force.drag() event here where I will drag the node in a position and leave the node and it will stay there.I have a working fiddle here,which is showing the relationship among the nodes.can anyone help me from here to do this event in this api? ..

this is the fiddle

```
var node = vis
  .selectAll("g.node")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vuCAx/

I think the changes should be made here

Answer (score 5):

The solution involves setting the 'fixed' node property to true on dragstart.

```
var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(data.nodes).enter().append(
    "svg:g").attr("class", "node").call(drag);

function dragstart(d) {
  d.fixed = true;
}
```

See here: [Sticky Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558)

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuCAx/1/

Documentation: [force.drag()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-drag)

> If you want dragged nodes to remain fixed after dragging, set the
>   fixed attribute to true on dragstart, as in the sticky force layout
>   example.